# HC[34]CookieManager does not append my login cookies

Tags: cookies, jmeter

Environment: JDK8,
Jmeter: 3.2

I am using HC4CookieManager (the only option that is available).

[Snapshot of my test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ1i2.png)

I issue a request with Basic Auth and I get the auth cookies back.
Unfortunately my server does not set a domain (Domain=;).

As a result (I think) HC4CookieManager entirely ignores the cookies with the result that I cannot perform operations on the server.

I see this error in the logs:

```
 2017-09-12 13:06:41,190 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Unable to add the cookie
org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException: Blank value for domain attribute
        at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.RFC2109DomainHandler.parse(RFC2109DomainHandler.java:61) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.PublicSuffixDomainFilter.parse(PublicSuffixDomainFilter.java:113) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.CookieSpecBase.parse(CookieSpecBase.java:113) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DefaultCookieSpec.parse(DefaultCookieSpec.java:145) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC4CookieHandler.addCookieFromHeader(HC4CookieHandler.java:125) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.addCookieFromHeader(CookieManager.java:373) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.saveConnectionCookies(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1519) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:485) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_102]
2017-09-12 13:06:41,327 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Unable to add the cookie
```

Is there a workaround to this? I have tried JDK7 with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line to the *user.properties* file:

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

and restart JMeter to pick the property up.

As per [HTTP Cookie Manager documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager):

> JMeter checks that received cookies are valid for the URL. This means that cross-domain cookies are not stored. If you have bugged behaviour or want Cross-Domain cookies to be used, define the JMeter property **"CookieManager.check.cookies=false"**.

So JMeter should be storing even invalid cookies given the aforementioned property is set to `false`

More comprehensive explanation with examples: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

Comment: I forgot to add - I have tried this workaround - it does not work. I have the exact same exception after I add it to user.properties and restart Jmeter.

Comment: My updated bin/user.properties has the setting CookieManager.check.cookies=false  and I have restarted Jmeter. I still get the stacktrace (and cookies are not sent): org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException: Blank value for domain attribute
        at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.RFC2109DomainHandler.parse(RFC2109DomainHandler.java:61) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.PublicSuffixDomainFilter.parse(PublicSuffixDomainFilter.java:113) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.CookieSpecBase.parse(CookieSpecBase.java:113)

Comment: Set `ignoreCookies` policy

Comment: I have tried with all the 8 options and I have the exact same problem. I am at my wit's end. Any help appreciated! Here is the Set-Cookie response header I get, in case that offers some hint:   Set-Cookie: X-JWT-ACCESS-TOKEN=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1OWIzOTE0MDA3MGZhNTAwMTdhNTJkMGMiLCJhdXRoU291cmNlIjoiaW50ZXJuYWwiLCJ0ZW5hbnROYW1lIjoiVE5UMCIsInJvbGVzIjpbIjU5YjM5MTNlMDcwZmE1MDAxN2E1MmQwYiJdLCJ0ZW5hbnRJZCI6IjU5YjM5MTNlMDcwZmE1MDAxN2E1MmQwYSIsImV4cCI6MTUwNTQ1Njk0NiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiJ9.mK-Q3xdO6mvB_HoiQcJr5GeeFx9l1lo1QfZeIeFY8gw;Version=-1;Comment=;Domain=;Path=/;Secure